# 5e What artisan skills or proficiencies would a character use to fletch arrows?

Tags: dnd-5e, crafting

My characters were running low on arrows during a battle.  They wanted to make more arrows in the field.  Did not see anything specific in the PHB. What kind of proficiencies or artisan tools would a player need to fletch arrows? Various sources mention wood crafting tools but nothing specific to artisan skills or proficiencies.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

From the comments (Thanks!) I believe I have a solution to share with my party.  For a member of an adventuring party to be able to fletch arrows in the field he would need to have Woodcarver's Tools AND Tool proficiency.  And as DM I would not allow anyone in the party who does not have both of those items/skills to be able to craft arrows. Thanks for helping 'craft' that solution.

Answer (score 14):

*Xanathar's Guide to Everything* gives new (or at least more explicit) uses for the crafting tools that were listed in the Player's Handbook. For crafting arrows, you need Woodcarver's Tools:

> ***Craft Arrows***. As part of a short rest, you can craft up to five arrows. As part of a long rest, you can craft up to twenty. You must have enough wood on hand to produce them.

Comment: wait, you don't need feathers for fletching?! Those arrows won't ever fly straight!

Comment: @Trish Most adventuring parties are assumed to carry around a live turkey for exactly this purpose.

Comment: @Trish: Feathers are not that important. The right amount of stiffness (called “spine”) is much more important. Also the center of gravity.

Comment: @Michael an unfletched arrow has an effective range of about 10 to 15 feet, a properly fletched one up to hundreds of yards.

Comment: @Trish: I don’t have my bow or any unfletched arrows with me right now, but I shot with unfletched arrows some 10 years ago or so and it didn’t work too badly. This article here also mentions that unfletched arrows should hit in a tight circle at 10–15 yards (13m) https://www.bowhunting.com/bowhunt101/bare-shaft-tuning-bow/

Comment: eh, yea, but your range is seriously reduced and accuracy too.

Comment: I’ve found another article which suggests 1.2cm accuracy at 18m with unfletched arrows. Perfectly fine for shooting some orcs if you ask me.

Comment: I prefer to engage my enemies at battlefield distances of 300 meters.

Comment: @Trish So you’re a multiclassed warlock/sorcerer using *eldritch blast* with Eldritch Spear, Spell Sniper, and Distant Spell?

Comment: @ThomasMarkov Nah, I use an ELB or even a locked-down LB with a windlass.

Comment: Keep in mind, this is the same set of rules that allows a forge cleric to make anything under a certain value out of metal, as long as it contains metal. So you could make studded leather armour out of nothing more than ingots of metal.

Comment: We do a certain amount of hand-waving as regards specific materials, as well as gear maintenance.  Nobody ever has to explicitly refletch an arrow because they fell out of a tree and damaged the feathers in their quiver, but we can probably just assume they carry around gut, feathers, whetstones, and other such material for the purpose of keeping their stuff in working shape during rests. It usually isn't fun for the players to be told they need to go side-quest to go kill a bird so they have feathers for fletching, so we kinda skip past it.